# Excel function to count row once for two criteria found in same cell

Tags: excel, unique, countif

My excel knowledge is very basic using my own research here and there so I would need some help from you guys.

I have a situation where I need to calculate the number of rows that contain certain date values which I converted it to text for certain reason (didn’t want to list them in separate rows).

E.g.

Col A.                       Col B.

Customer Name, Date Purchase

Andy.                   1/2/2021 , 2/3/2021

Jenny.                  2/2/2021 , 3/4/2021

Mary.                   1/3/2021 , 1/5/2021

I want to count the number of unique customers who purchased between February and May 2021 for the above case, but I didn’t know how I should proceed from an existing countifs formula I had that looks like the following:

=countif(B:B, “*/2/2021*”) + countif(B:B, “*/3/2021*”) + countif(B:B, “*/4/2021*”) + countif(B:B, “*/5/2021*”)

This formula had returned the value as 9 based on the following results

February : 2

March : 2

April : 4

May : 1

which I didn’t want as I want the count number of different customers I had instead (for this case I want the cell with a formula that can return the result as “3” , not the number of time purchased).

Please help me to make a suitable formula works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By adding an indicator in Column C that shows whether or not each customer satisfies your purchase requirements you could simply sum these up at the bottom to count the number of unique customers.

Hopefully the image below containing the formula in Column C (essentially checking that each customer has **at least one** purchase between February and May) will resolve your issue.  I added a Dummy customer that doesn't satisfy these dates just a check so the total unique customers is still 3 (Cell C6 which uses a formula of '=COUNTIF(C2:C5,"Y")').

[image]

You mention the possibility of having 100 purchase dates, are these all recorded in text format in Column B?  I would have thought that would make things more difficult to track than having 100 individual columns (though this doesn't affect your query above).

Comment: Yes the second date is the second purchase, so on and forth new dates will just keep adding on. It may not be feasible to create another column. Anyway it is not about customer’s satisfaction or so. I am just quoting an example of my database which is kind of sensitive to reveal. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I can’t add multiple dates in one cell so I ended up using text format. Else I would love it to have it maintained as date format which make things easier for me but I can’t  due to certain figure or statistic that I need to generate, similar to the counting of number of customers who purchased within a period.

Comment: Is it not feasible to add the additional purchases within new columns?  I understand your data is sensitive and you have other statistics to consider but I'm struggling to think of any situations where it would be preferable to have one single column with an ever-increasing string of dates in text format versus having all applicable purchase dates in their own column and being able to work off those.

Comment: Probably you can just let me know your suggestion of having a new column and elaborate further how is the formula like for the new column or what should the new column be counting first. Do you mean if I have 100 purchase date to record for same customer, I will need to have 100 extra columns to capture each date? If this is what you mean then it couldn’t apply for my case. It would look very messy as there are other columns or fields to capture. Let me know better your solution, I will see if it could apply for my situation. Thanks much Paul!

Comment: I've edited my initial response now which hopefully resolves your query based on using an indicator for every customer to show whether or not they made a purchase between February and May, then you can just sum these up rather than trying to work with all purchase dates for all customers. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Paul! I eventually decided to do it with your suggestion but put them on separate sheet and just hide it. It’s works as I wanted now. Thanks much!